# Why I cannot SSH as root into my android?

Tags: root-access, ssh

I set an public key auth SSH server in my rooted Note 4 through Dropbear (Terminal IDE). I am being able to log in as any user, except root. I get:

```
 [2085] Jan 31 20:05:21 exit after auth (root): child failed
 Connection to 192.168.nn.nn closed.
```

I've read that this is shell-related problem, but no idea which, or how to fix it.
I want to log in as root since I get constant permission denied when trying to look at the /sdcard.

This is the script that starts the server:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

base="/data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files"
dropbear=$base/system/bin/dropbear

id="1023"
gid="1028,1015"
username="gato"
w="-w"
if [ "$1" == "root" ]; then
    id=0
    gid=0
    username="root"
    w=""
fi

$dropbear \
    -A -N $username -U $id -G $gid \
    -C jtkkRKJ6993irJTjRJ993irJTj8496j \
    -d $base/.ssh/dropbear_dss_host_key \
    -r $base/.ssh/dropbear_rsa_host_key \
    -R $base/.ssh/authorized_keys \
    -F -E -s $w -g -p 22 &
```

These are the permissions in $base/.ssh:

```
 # ls -la .ssh
 drwx------    2 0        0             4096 Jan 28 23:43 .
 drwxrwxrwx   17 10223    10223         4096 Jan 31 22:25 ..
 -rw-------    1 0        0              382 Jan 28 23:43 authorized_keys
 -rw-------    1 0        0              458 Jan 28 23:43 dropbear_dss_host_key
 -rw-------    1 0        0              426 Jan 28 23:43 dropbear_rsa_host_key
 -rw-------    1 0        0             1798 Jan 28 23:43 known_hosts
```

Comment: are you sure dropbear itself is in fact running with root privileges?

Comment: @mikky: Well, it's being started by root itself after a su -. Remember that I can login as non root even with pubkeys. This is a shell problem.

Comment: The error message suggests a permission problem - seems to me that dropbear cannot fork a shell with root permissions.
I just tried your script and it works for me (root can log in) but I'm using dropbear installed via different app. Using CM11.

Comment: Mmmm... maybe it's that... I'll try to find another dropbear app. Thanks!!

Comment: @mikky doesn't CM always ship with `ro.secure=0` – i.e. you get a root shell directly when using `adb shell`, without any call to `su`? Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: BTW: anyone knows how to specify multiple groups with dropbear? Only the first one is recognized, at least in the version I have.

Comment: @izzy I don't think so, adb is a separate subsystem. In this case shell is forked from dropbear which tries to change the EID while with adb shell it's forked from adb itself directly. In CM the superuser settings differentiates between adb root and app root. That being said, I still have no idea what may cause the problem.

Comment: I was aware that there's no relation to ADB here, of course; I've just thought there might be a similar setting dropbear honors, for security reasons. `ro.secure` is (or should be) honored by `adbd` at boot time. There's a second setting (I forgot the name) for whether it's allowed to switch to root mode on demand. Dropbear might honor that second one as well. A helful article on our sister site might be: [run dropbear ssh server from android as system user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16891509/2533433)

Comment: Also worth cross-checking: [How To Install SSH Server As Root On Android 4.4 KitKat](http://www.megaleecher.net/Installing_SSH_Server_With_Root_On_Android)

Comment: The main reason to use dropbear as root was to allow easy RW of the external sdcard. So I decided to go the secure route: to set proper permissions on everything (as I should have done from the beginning). I changed dropbear to use the same id as the one of terminal emulator, but gid=1028. With that, I am able to write both in the sdcard and in the external sdcard, rsync, etc.

Comment: @Izzy, I think I know what you're talking about with `ro.secure`. Can't remember the name of the other settings as well but I belive it is only taken into account by the `su` binary, not the others since it should be managed system-wide which a proper `su` in conjucntion with some kind of Super* app (_SuperUser_ in case of CM11) takes care of.
It's likely dropbear already runs as root in Luis's case, the script seems ok, especially if he can log in as non-root user. Although this might need confirmation. 
Empirically, the problem is in Terminal IDE's dropbear binary, since "it works for me".

Comment: "I belive it is only taken into account by the `su` binary": which is what apps invoke to get root privileges AFAIK. As for "the other setting": wasn't that `persist.sys.safemode=0` for a "root-adbd"? Worth a try here as well, I'd say: including a `setprop persist.sys.safemode=0` (and `=1` to revert back – or better using `getprop persist.sys.safemode` to first figure the original setting).

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: I have the same problem: "Exit (root): Child failed". Did you finally find a solution?

Comment: @tokland: I start dropbear with `gid="1028"`. I can write and read the external SD card. I was unable to use it as root.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: Thx! got it working. While not shown in the options, -G is a valid option. As you, I can only use it with a non-root user, but I run "su" after and I have root access.

Comment: Yep, this is what I did. A pain, but safer.

Comment: I have dropbear v0.53.1 and i did not have -G option. Also, I don´t know where to download another dropbear binary for my samsung gt-n5110